# C Code type declaration of parameters outside of of parameter list

Tags: c

This syntax for declaring parameter types:

```
void fxn_name (var_name)
  type_name var_name;
{
  ... 
}
```

Does it have a name?

Comment: I know it by the "K&R style declaration" name

Answer (score 1):

The C standard literally calls this “old style”. C 2018 note 149:

> If both function types are “old style”, parameter types are not compared.

It refers to the whole function definition as one with an “identifier list” (the `var_name` in parentheses in your example) in contrast to the modern style with a “parameter type list” (such as `int x`, in `void foo(int x)`). C 2018 6.7.6.3 15:

> … If one type has a parameter type list and the other type is specified by a function definition that contains a (possibly empty) identifier list,…

In the formal grammar, the declarations after the function declarator are called a *declaration-list*. C 6.9.1 1:

> *function-definition*:
>         *declaration-specifiers* *declarator* *declaration-list*<sub>opt</sub> *compound-statement*
>
> *declaration-list*:
>         *declaration*
>         *declaration-list* *declaration*

This token, *declaration-list*, is pretty generic sounding, but it is not used anywhere else in the grammar, so a *declaration-list* is always the list of old-style declarations after a function declarator and before its *compound-statement*. So, if you call it a *declaration-list*, nobody could say you are wrong.

The standard also uses “declaration list” in plain text (in contrast to the formal grammar), and this is the only sense in which that phrase appears in the standard. However, since this is not part of the formal grammar, it would be harder to claim that this is the only meaning of “declaration list,” as that clearly is a general phrase subject to obvious interpretation as simply any list of declarations.